# Issue with non responsive vertically centered div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div vertically centered inside a parent div.At the same time I don't want the child div not to be responsive.

Here is the html code

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div style="background: url('http://www.screensavergift.com/wp-content/uploads/GoldenNature2-610x320.jpg') no-repeat; background-position: 25% 50%; background-size: cover;" class="menu_item"></div>
    <div class="menu-box-border"></div>
    <div class="menu-box-content-box">
         <h3>Some Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a demo here -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/4eewp8x0/7/

As you can see the semi transparent box with overlay is always staying at the bottom and on browser resize the box is also resizing and as a result the overlay box is causing problem to the text.

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the child div to be responsive or not? I don't quite understand what you want.

Comment: Yes the child div should not be responsive and horizontally centered.

Comment: So you mean, as the browser resizes, the overlay box should remain the same at all time, instead of changing its own size?

Comment: yes exactly...also if you see the demo then the overlay box is not centered. I was trying to adjust the top and bottom pixels but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a well-known trick to do this, you can read it on https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

This will give you this: http://jsfiddle.net/4eewp8x0/8/

However, as we have more and more powerful tools of CSS3, I'd like to present some more tricks.

1. CSS Transform

The essence of this trick is that we absolutely position the child at `(50%,50%)`, and then do a translate of `(-50%,-50%)`

You will have this: http://jsfiddle.net/4eewp8x0/9/

2. Flex Layout

At last, people who are filled up with fury toward the difficulties aligning elements come up with flex layout.

You can read about flex layout here:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You will have this: http://jsfiddle.net/4eewp8x0/11/

Comment: Simply brilliant. Thank you so much for explaining step by step and advanced css. Learnt a lot.